# WebView shows on Android but not on iOS Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

this is my WebView

```
    <WebView x:Name="webview" Source="http://google.com" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="500" >
        </WebView>
```

it's show on Android but not on ios,i also added

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

to info.plist iOS but it dosen't work!what's problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You code looks goods. Are you sure you Mac can access the website http://google.com in the browser? Or can you share us a sample which can reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. Use `https://` instead of `http`.
2. give width too to the webview.

Above two should help, but even if above solutions doesn't work.try adding like this in info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>google.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
...
```